# ReactJS -> how do I make restricted routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a couple of react routes that look like this:

```
<Route exact path='/Home' component={Products}/>
<Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>
<Route path='/Register' component={Register}/>
<Route path='/ProfilePage' component={ProfilePage}/>
```

And I would like to make it so that the `profilepage` route would be accessible only by a user that has logged in but I have almost no ideas as to how that would happen. I've thought of creating a state that would keep the `loginStatus` until a cookie with the `loginStatus` expires(for example after a week or so) and then somehow if the `loginStatus='logged'` then the `profilepage` router will be accessible otherwise it would redirect to some page showing an error, using another route. I've got no idea how to do that though.

Comment: If you keep the user's information in state (e.g., email or name or something), then just condition the display of those routes off of the existence of that information in state. Importantly, nothing on your frontend is for security; your backend should do the actual enforcement.

Comment: I keep the user's information in a database

Comment: Your cookie method is correct, you should be able to access to cookies from react and check their values in the frontend using simple if else like `if not authorized` redirect here, using react HOC.

Comment: additionally, i'd suggest you explore the concept of JWT, as they are newer and more popular, cookie methods are quite old, but still in use.

Comment: I suppose JWT is more secure than the cookies method?

Answer (score 0):

Try create a custom route component with login condicional and Redirect:
Example:

```js
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return isAuthenticated === true ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/Login",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```